# What is the intended use of the tie-after character (⁀ ) in TeX

Tags: accents

In Computer Modern, the tie-after character (⁀ ) is defined in the cmmi* faces (math italic). The kernings inside the cmmi* are used math accent positioning but the text use is not clear to me.

What is the intended (which probably is also the most frequent) text use of the tie-after character (⁀ ) in TeX?

Comment: I would say, there is no use of that character in `TeX` at all. It is used in typesetting of predominantly math-related topics, which uses TeX etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The “tie after” accent is used in a couple of places in the TeXbook for transliterating from Cyrillic:

```
Akademi\t\i a Nauk SSSR, Doklady
Serge\u\i\ \t Iur'ev
```

[image]

It should denote that the character is single, a transliteration of Я and Ю respectively. A more standard (but imprecise) transliteration would be the one currently used for passport names (ICAO)

```
Akademiia
Sergei Iurev
```

or the one common in English speaking countries ([BGN/PCGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGN/PCGN_romanization_of_Russian))

```
Akademiya
Sergey Yur'ev
```

A more precise transliteration according to [ISO 9:1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9) would be

```
Akademiâ
Sergej Ûr’ev
```

The scheme used by Knuth seems to be [ALA-LC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALA-LC_romanization_for_Russian).

What are the kerning pairs about? Since the character is essentially unused in math mode and rare in text mode, Knuth decided to place it in the math letter font and use it also for the `\skewchar` feature. When a math accent is placed over a letter, it is skewed by the amount of the kerning between the letter and the `\skewchar` (which for `cmmi10` is precisely the “tie after”); each font can have its own `\skewchar`. This allows for the accent to be set at a suitable place over the letter; the amount of kerning depends on the letter's shape and has been carefully computed.

In `omlcmm.fd` we find

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OML}{cmm}{\skewchar\font127 }
```

and in `omscmsy.fd`

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OMS}{cmsy}{\skewchar\font48 }
```

and in `plain.tex` there are matching declarations

```
\skewchar\teni='177 \skewchar\seveni='177 \skewchar\fivei='177
\skewchar\tensy='60 \skewchar\sevensy='60 \skewchar\fivesy='60
```